# Modifying children in a org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section causes exception

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a problem that I am facing with using `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section`, that if I add children to it and modify the children by enabling them or setting text on them I get an exception. I have written a small snippet to easily reproduce the problem below:

```java
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section;

public class SectionTest {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display ();
        final Shell shell = new Shell (display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        Button b = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                addSection(shell);
            }
        });
        b.setText("Add");

        addSection(shell);

        shell.setSize(300, 300);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            try {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                    display.sleep();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                MessageDialog.openError(shell, "Error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void addSection(Composite parent) {
        Section section = new Section(parent, Section.TITLE_BAR | Section.TREE_NODE | Section.CLIENT_INDENT);
        section.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        section.setText("Hello");
        //section.setSize(1, 1);

        // Add the check button for enabling/disabling this group
        Button enableControl = new Button(section, SWT.CHECK);
        enableControl.setText("Enable");
        section.setTextClient(enableControl);

        Composite client = new Composite(section, SWT.NONE);
        section.setClient(client);
        client.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        Button b = new Button(client, SWT.PUSH);
        b.setText("one");

        b = new Button(client, SWT.PUSH);
        b.setText("two");
        parent.layout();
    }
}
```

If you run the code a dialog will appear with an add button. Clicking on the add button will produce the exception.

Exception text:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4342)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.init(Image.java:1558)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section.onPaint(Section.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite$1.paintControl(ExpandableComposite.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PRINTCLIENT(Composite.java:1639)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4590)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2440)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.callWindowProc(Button.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowTextW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowText(OS.java:3461)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button._setText(Button.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.setText(Button.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.swt.snippets.SectionTest.addSection(SectionTest.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.swt.snippets.SectionTest.access$0(SectionTest.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.swt.snippets.SectionTest$1.widgetSelected(SectionTest.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.swt.snippets.SectionTest.main(SectionTest.java:39)
```

This problem occurs with 32-bit JRE (and eclipse) on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. This same problem is not reproducible on Windows XP (32-bit).

My question is, what I am doing wrong that causes this exception. If you notice I add a section using the same method before the shell opens and it runs without any problems, however once the shell is open and visible calling the same `addSection(Composite)` method causes exceptions.

> **NOTE**: Uncommenting the line 'section.setSize(1, 1);' in `addSection(Composite)` will "hide" the problem, but it does not seem like the right thing to do. What is correct way to use Sections?

---

> **Edit:** Found an issue already reported in ecilpse, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=309443, which seems to be the same finding as this question.

Comment: I didn't add the exception to avoid too much text in the question. But the snippet will allow you to easily reproduce the exception. Do you prefer if I add the exception trace as well?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer it. Maybe someone who tries to run the code will get a different exception or none at all, so it would help to know which one you got.

Comment: Ok added the exception trace log.

Comment: Try calling `parent.layout()` right after the section was created in `addSection`. I can't prove it, but I guess the error is caused by cached layout sizes in the parent.

Comment: Well there are workarounds, but my questions is whether I am doing something wrong or does this look like a defect in eclipse. Another workaround is that before creating the button if I call `section.setExpanded(true)`, the exception goes away.

Comment: This seems like a platform-specific issue in Eclipse. I tried this code in my 4.2 installation on 64 bit OS X 10.8, and works as expected; also, the code seems to be normal. I suggest searching for a Bugzilla issue, and if none exist, then creating one.

Comment: Found an issue already reported (back in 2010) that seems to highlight this issue.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=309443